# purpose of ts.html files in angular

Tags: angular

I am working on an angular 2 application. 
For all the components and templates, I see corresponding ts.html files which are autogenerated on the build. 
Why are they generated and what is their purpose?

Comment: Read about the [architecture of Angular](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/architecture.html)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the Angular CLI to build your project / files, this is actually done by convention, following the official [Angular Style Guide](https://angular.io/styleguide)

Also, it makes the structure of you files in your project much more logic, if you would give your template files other file names then your TypeScript files it would get a mess at some point.

So my advice, stick to the Angular Style Guide conventions, maybe they aren't all that fun to follow in the beginning but in the long run you'll understand why.